# libavcodec not found even though ffmpeg has been built and installed

Tags: build, ffmpeg, libavcodec

I have a program that depends on `libavcodec` on Linux. I have downloaded the ffmpeg sources and built them using `./configure`, `make` and `make install`. But the program that depends on `libavcodec` refuses to recognize the libraries. What have I done wrong? I am building on Ubuntu 13.10.

Comment: Need more information. What does "refuses to recognize" mean? Do you get an error? What error? What is the program? Did you try LD_LIBRARY_PATH?

Answer (score 0):

This may be due to the search path for the Linux dynamic linker. You may want to read the manpage for ld.so.